# Cannnot download data through spatialLIBD R package

Tags: r

When I tried to download the example data of Human DLPFC spatial transcriptomics data from the 10x Genomics Visium platform, I got the error below:
.

```
library(spatialLIBD)
sce <- fetch_data(type = 'sce')
  |======================================================================| 100%

snapshotDate(): 2021-10-19
adding rname 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4wcvtdq428y73p/Human_DLPFC_Visium_processedData_sce_scran_spatialLIBD.Rdata?dl=1'
Error in BiocFileCache::bfcrpath(bfc, url) : 
  not all 'rnames' found or unique.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: download failed
  web resource path: ‘https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4wcvtdq428y73p/Human_DLPFC_Visium_processedData_sce_scran_spatialLIBD.Rdata?dl=1’
  local file path: ‘/data1/home/zhaolan/.cache/R/BiocFileCache/72e91577fb99_Human_DLPFC_Visium_processedData_sce_scran_spatialLIBD.Rdata%3Fdl%3D1’
  reason: Timeout was reached: [www.dropbox.com] Failed to connect to www.dropbox.com port 443 after 5221 ms: Connection timed out 
2: bfcadd() failed; resource removed
  rid: BFC3
  fpath: ‘https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4wcvtdq428y73p/Human_DLPFC_Visium_processedData_sce_scran_spatialLIBD.Rdata?dl=1’
  reason: download failed 
3: In value[[3L]](cond) : 
trying to add rname 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4wcvtdq428y73p/Human_DLPFC_Visium_processedData_sce_scran_spatialLIBD.Rdata?dl=1' produced error:
  bfcadd() failed; see warnings()
```

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Some institutions close ports and restrict downloading stuff for security reasons.

Comment: I used the VPN but I still can't download the Rdata. Is there any solution to this problem?